# A value of type 'MqttMessage' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MqttPublishMessage'

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

Every example I see is nearly identical to the code below. For some reason, this does not work form me. The problem is when I try to assign `final MqttPublishMessage message`, it is saying that `c[0].payload` is of type 'MqttMessage' which cannot be assigned to a variable of type 'MqttPublishMessage'.

```dart
MqttServerClient client = new MqttServerClient(serverUri, clientId);

client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c){
    final MqttPublishMessage message = c[0].payload; // Cannot assign type
    final payload = MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(message.payload.message);

    print('Received message:$payload from topic: ${c[0].topic}>');
});
```

I've tried casting which also doesn't work. I've copied the code exactly and nothing seemed to work. What is going on?

Comment: Hm, that's strange. But mine is `final String payload = MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(message.payload.message);`

Comment: Also it might be a typo. See --> `print('Received message:$payload from topic: <${c[0].topic}>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the full example provided [here](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/blob/master/example/mqtt_server_client.dart)

```
client.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? c) {
    final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
    final pt =
        MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message!);

    /// The above may seem a little convoluted for users only interested in the
    /// payload, some users however may be interested in the received publish message,
    /// lets not constrain ourselves yet until the package has been in the wild
    /// for a while.
    /// The payload is a byte buffer, this will be specific to the topic
    print(
        'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
    print('');
  });
```

As you can see he's creating the variable without the type, and he's doing a recast:

`final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;`

If this doesn't works, I would look for some errors in the client setup or maybe the data you are receiveing is not exactly what you are expecting to receive.

Comment: `final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;` fixed my IDE error. I actually got a suggestion saying `c![0]` will never be null. Upon running, I got an error saying `client.updates!.listen` was selecting a null object but that I fixed it with `client.updates?.listen`.

Comment: That's becouse of Null Safety. It has been introduced with Flutter 2.0. https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety